# How to Implement Sass into Underscores Theme with Bootstrap for Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, sass, wordpress-theming

I was able to create a Wordpress theme that I am working on, using my local machine. The issue I am having is incorporating Sass into the Underscores Starter theme, with Twitter Bootstrap's Sass and Wordpress.

I was creating the fixed-top bootstrap navigational bar. I managed to add the proper code to include WP_Walker_Nav in my functions.php file, but this is what my navigation looked like [My Bootstrap Nav](http://s25.postimg.org/7rm8l8w0f/Bootstrap_Nav_Screenshot.png).

The content is too close to the fixed-top navigation and I wasn't able to control the body tag styles to provide padding of at least 60px from the top.

I was wondering if someone can guide me in the direction on how to incorporate Twitter Bootstrap's Sass and Font-Awesome's Sass into Underscore's Wordpress theme.

I'm struggling with the proper workflow. For my Wordpress default style.css, all I would do is put

```
    @import url("css/style.css");
```

underneath Wordpress Stylesheet default comments.

I have a folder labeled sass (for all my scss files) and a folder css (for all my compiled css). In my style.scss, I import bootstrap and font-awesome's sass files, and I create a separate scss file (main.scss) to use for my custom styling, but nothing works when I create a variable in my main.scss file.

I would set my style.scss file like this:

```
    @import 'main';
    @import 'bootstrap-sass';
    @import 'font-awesome';
```

For example:

```
    $padding10: 10px;
    body {
         padding-top: ($padding10 * 6)
    }
```

nothing happens when I set up my body tag. Please tell me what I am doing wrong, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering about how to do this: the `_S` Underscores theme [added direct support](http://themeshaper.com/2014/08/11/sass-comes-to-_s/) for generating a starter theme with a sass-based architecture last year, which I only recently found out about. If you click the “Advanced Options” link on the Underscores main page, you can then select the `_sassify!` option and you’re on your way. From there, it should be clear to you how to wire in Bootstrap. The generated `sass/styles.scss` file in your new theme is a very well organized and documented list of imports, to which you can add Bootstrap however you wish (via Bower, direct download, whatever).

As a side note, you can automate this and make it even easier via [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org), which very recently [added support](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1638) for the sassify option to their [`wp scaffold _s` subcommand](http://wp-cli.org/commands/scaffold/_s/), which looks something like:

```bash
wp-cli scaffold _s my-sassy-theme --theme_name="My Sassy Theme" --sassify
```

(Note that as of this writing, there hasn’t been a release of wp-cli with that feature; you can use it immediately, however, by [installing the wp-cli nightly](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/wiki/Alternative-Install-Methods#installing-nightly-via-phar).)